# Windows Phone update/refresh binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a textblock in my listbox called "feedTitle" which I want to change the forground color of. I use Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NewsTextColorConverter}}" for the binding of the forground color. Now the strange problem is that, if I choose a color in the listpicker("Lys" or "Dark" value) it runs the IValueConverter Convert method, but it dont show the color in the GUI, only if I restart my whole app it shows the color I chosen. It's like it only set the color of the forground of the textblock once.

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="feedListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="feedListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="24" Name="feedTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NewsTextColorConverter}}" Text="{Binding Title.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And in my app file:

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <converter:NewsTextColorConverter xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:NordjyskeRss" x:Key="NewsTextColorConverter" />
</Application.Resources>
```

I use a listpicker where a user select the value "Mørk" or "Lys" and then I want the textblock forground color to update its forground color. I call the Convert method and pass null as arguments, it seems to run the method fine:

MainPage.cs

```
private void lpkThemes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure we don't handle the event during initiation.
        if (e.RemovedItems != null && e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            if (this.lpkThemes.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                settings[THEMES_SETTING_KEY] = lpkThemes.SelectedItem.ToString();
                if (lpkThemes.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Mørk")
                {
                    n.Convert(null, null, null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    n.Convert(null, null, null, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where I use a IValueConverter to check for what color to use on the textblock and then add it:

MainPage.cs

```
public class NewsTextColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    protected IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    protected const string THEMES_SETTING_KEY = "Themes";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (settings.Contains(THEMES_SETTING_KEY))
        {
            string themesValue = (string)settings[THEMES_SETTING_KEY];
            if (themesValue == "Mørk")
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            }
        }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        //throw new NotSupportedException("ColorToBurshConverter only supports converting from Color and String");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redesign your app in the following way:

1. Add the following line into your app.xaml or page resources: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushListItemsForeground" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />`
2. Replace `Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NewsTextColorConverter}}"` with `Foreground="{StaticResource brushListItemsForeground}"`
3. In your SelectionChanged:

`var brush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["brushListItemsForeground"];` if you’ve added the brush to app.xaml, or `= (SolidColorBrush)this.Resources["brushListItemsForeground"];` if you’ve added the brush to page resources. Then change the `Color` property of the brush based on your settings.

P.S. There’re also other correct ways: e.g. create a `SettingsContainer` class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, add it into some resource dictionary `<local:SettingsContainer x:Key="mySettings" />`, then bind to its properties e.g. `Foreground="{Binding listItemsForeground, Source={StaticResource mySettings}}"`, when you need to change the value, change the `listItemsForeground` property of your class and raise PropertyChanged.

Currently, you’re abusing value converter using then as value providers, they were not designed for that, and that is why you have issues updating those values.

Comment: Thanks. But i ended up using some hardcoded colors which show up nice both in dark and light theme.